# How to use Net::SMTP over SOCKS proxy?

Tags: ruby, networking, smtp, socks

I'm doing this, in Ruby 2.6:

```
require 'net/smtp'
Net::SMTP.start('smtp.gmail.com', 457).do |smtp|
  smtp.helo('gmail.com')
end
```

Now I want to do exactly the same, but over SOCKS4/5 proxy. I can't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of [Net::SMTP](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/net/smtp.rb) it would seem like it doesn't have built-in support for SOCKS proxies.

A couple of ideas:

1. Is your Ruby interpreter built with SOCKS support? If yes, then you'd be able to use [SOCKSSocket class](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/d48783bb0236db505fe1205d1d9822309de53a36/ext/socket/sockssocket.c). Create a subclass of Net::SMTP and override [`tcp_socket` method](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/025206d0dd29266771f166eb4f59609af602213a/lib/net/smtp.rb#L538-L540) to use `SOCKSSocket` instead of `TCPSocket`.
2. Use [ruby-proxifier](https://github.com/samuelkadolph/ruby-proxifier) gem (although it seems rather old).
3. Re-implement `SOCKSSocket` in pure Ruby (connecting through SOCKS4 isn't too hard, SOCKS5 is slightly more complicated, see [this example](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/zhenkyle/shadowsocks_ruby#Example_SOCKS4_Client_Protocol_in_35_lines) for reference) or find an existing implementation (although I haven't been able to find one).